# Group rows together by 2 column tree connection

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the table below where there is an `amount` that can be charged or credited.  Each row Each one of these entries gets an `id`.  Now you can undo a charge by giving a credit in exactly the same amount and reversing that/. If that's the case the `reversed_by` field will tell which `id` will flip it.  But you can reverse a reverse as many times as you want.  So for example, id `8fa22925` was never reversed and should be in a group by itself (`4`).  `4e35510a` was reversed by `c362b6c5` and the reversing stopped so they make group `3`.  `beca097b` was reversed by `dc102220` but in turn this was reversed by `84529ee0`.  I know that `id` and `reversed_by` form a simple tree structure in 2 column format.

How can I use Postgres to add grouping to all connections as shown in my desired output below?

I don't care what the `group` is...could be int, varchar, original/last id, etc.

Schema

```
CREATE TABLE delete_me (
    amount Int,
    id varchar(255),
    reversed_by varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO delete_me
VALUES
( 12,'ea75921c', NULL     ),
(-12,'e72d92d9','ea75921c'),
(-12,'84529ee0', NULL     ),
( 12,'dc102220','84529ee0'),
(-12,'beca097b','dc102220'),
(  8,'c362b6c5', NULL     ),
( -8,'4e35510a','c362b6c5'),
( 10,'8fa22925', NULL     )
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM delete_me;
```

| amount | id | reversed_by |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | ea75921c |  |
| -12 | e72d92d9 | ea75921c |
| -12 | 84529ee0 |  |
| 12 | dc102220 | 84529ee0 |
| -12 | beca097b | dc102220 |
| 8 | c362b6c5 |  |
| -8 | 4e35510a | c362b6c5 |
| 10 | 8fa22925 |  |

**Desired Output**

| amount | id | reversed_by | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | ea75921c |  | 1 |
| -12 | e72d92d9 | ea75921c | 1 |
| -12 | 84529ee0 |  | 2 |
| 12 | dc102220 | 84529ee0 | 2 |
| -12 | beca097b | dc102220 | 2 |
| 8 | c362b6c5 |  | 3 |
| -8 | 4e35510a | c362b6c5 | 3 |
| 10 | 8fa22925 |  | 4 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jYgCgrgEK7TiUiG9VW6iPd/0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using the root of the "reversing tree" as the "group indicator"?

```
with recursive cte as (
  select dm.*, id as root, 1 as level
  from delete_me dm
  where dm.reversed_by is null
  union all
  select ch.*, cte.root, cte.level + 1
  from delete_me ch
    join cte on cte.id = ch.reversed_by
)
select *
from cte
order by root, level
```

This returns the following result based on your sample data:

```
amount | id       | reversed_by | root     | level
-------+----------+-------------+----------+------
   -12 | 84529ee0 |             | 84529ee0 |     1
    12 | dc102220 | 84529ee0    | 84529ee0 |     2
   -12 | beca097b | dc102220    | 84529ee0 |     3
    10 | 8fa22925 |             | 8fa22925 |     1
     8 | c362b6c5 |             | c362b6c5 |     1
    -8 | 4e35510a | c362b6c5    | c362b6c5 |     2
    12 | ea75921c |             | ea75921c |     1
   -12 | e72d92d9 | ea75921c    | ea75921c |     2
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9fc98c5368b474f014bc84c0bef36459)

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly!!!  You can even use the recursive cte inside another cte in postgres